# SVG arent supported in new wordpress version

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I have the new 5.8.1 wordpress, but svg in the media uploader aren't working anymore.

I used this code to integrate svgs:

```
function cc_mime_types($mimes) {
  $mimes['svg'] = 'image/svg+xml';
  return $mimes;
}
add_filter('upload_mimes', 'cc_mime_types');
```

Why is it not working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You first need to mention the file type and extension.
here is my code for that !

```
// Wp v4.7.1 and higher
add_filter( 'wp_check_filetype_and_ext', function($data, $file, $filename, $mimes) {
  $filetype = wp_check_filetype( $filename, $mimes );
  return [
      'ext'             => $filetype['ext'],
      'type'            => $filetype['type'],
      'proper_filename' => $data['proper_filename']
  ];

}, 10, 4 );

function cc_mime_types( $mimes ){
  $mimes['svg'] = 'image/svg+xml';
  return $mimes;
}
add_filter( 'upload_mimes', 'cc_mime_types' );

function fix_svg() {
  echo '<style type="text/css">
        .attachment-266x266, .thumbnail img {
             width: 100% !important;
             height: auto !important;
        }
        </style>';
}
add_action( 'admin_head', 'fix_svg' );
```

Comment: You don't answer at "Why this isn't working ?"

Comment: I have edited my answer ., kindly check it.

Answer (score 0):

After WP 4.7 you dont need to use svg+xml with your current code OR you have to specify file type as example below

```
function cc_mime_types($mimes) {
  $mimes['svg'] = 'image/svg';
  return $mimes;
}
add_filter('upload_mimes', 'cc_mime_types');
```

You can check alot of different solutions here - https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/313951/how-to-upload-svg-in-wordpress-4-9-8