# WordPress WooCommerce product category Thumbnail not support SVG image

Tags: wordpress, svg, woocommerce, categories, hook-woocommerce

[image]> **i have upload product category image but .svg not support**

> Blockquote

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SVG arent supported in new wordpress version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69382629/svg-arent-supported-in-new-wordpress-version)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function additional_mime_types($mime_types) {
    $mime_types['svg'] = 'image/svg'; //Adding svg extension
    return $mime_types;
}

add_filter('upload_mimes', 'additional_mime_types', 1, 1);
```

Add additional support file types by adding this to your active theme `functions.php` file.

Snippet inspired from [here](https://www.webtoffee.com/how-to-get-support-for-webp-images-in-product-import-export-plugin-for-woocommerce/)

Comment: woocommerce category not upload svg support please check

Comment: Using the code snippet it's uploading SVG to category image :)

Comment: without plugin SVG upload

Comment: Without the code snippet its not possible

Comment: I would also suggest adding `$mime_types['svgz'] = 'image/svg+xml';`, I have trouble with some svgs from time to time, add this as well helped with that